# an auth method over HTTP(s) and/or REST with libraries for Python and/or C++

Tags: c++, python, http, authentication, rest

Because I don't exactly know how any auth method works I want to write my own.
So, what I want to do is the following.
A client sends over HTTPs  username+password(or SHA1(username+password)) 
the server gets the username+password and generates a big random number and stores it in
a table called TOKENS(in some database) along with his IP, 
then it give the client that exact number.
From now on, all the requests made by the client are accompanied by that TOKEN
and if the TOKEN is not in the table TOKENS then any such request will fail.
If the user hasn't made any requests in 2 hours the TOKEN will expire.
If the user wants to log out he makes a request '/logout' to the server and the server
deletes from the table TOKENS the entry containing his token but *ONLY* if the request to
'/logout' originates from his IP.

Maybe I am reinventing the wheel... this wouldn't be very good so my question is if there
is some auth system that already works like this , what is it's name , does it have any OSS C++ libraries or Python libraries available ?

I am not sure if finding such an auth system and configuring it would take longer than
writing it myself, on the other hand I know security is a delicate problem so I am
approaching this with some doubt that I am capable of writing something secure enough.

Also, is there a good OSS C++ HTTP library ? I'm planning to write a RESTful Desktop
client for a web app. Depending on the available libraries I will choose if I'll write it
in C++ or Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing such authentication system over ordinary HTTP, you are vulnerable to replay attacks. Attacker could sniff out the SHA1(username+password) and just resend it every time he/she wants to log in. To make such authentication system work, you will need to use a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).

You might want to look at [HTTP Digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) for tips.

Comment: what if he sniffs the nonce as well ?
even more ... he has access to the RESTful Desktop Client because
it will be publicly downloadable.

Comment: also , what does the dotted horizontal line in the wikipedia diagram
mean ? does it mean something special as opposed to the continous one ?

Comment: Nonce is only used once, which is why you cannot use that value for replay attacks. What do you mean with horizontal line? Do you mean the colon (:)? If you mean that, it is just a colon :) The values are separated by the colon character ':'.

Comment: This drawing , the horizontal lines with the arrow at the end ...   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Nonce-cnonce-uml.svg

Comment: Ah, I see. That looks like a UML sequence diagram. Dashed horizontal lines are used to indicate return values.

Comment: so any thoughts on the other questions ?

Comment: There is [cURL][1] which has C++ bindings. I haven't tried it myself, but it should support HTTP Digest authentication. Don't reinvent the wheel. [1]: http://curlpp.org/

Answer (score 0):

> Because I don't exactly know how any auth method works I want to write my own

How could you ever write something you don't understand? Learn at least one, the underlaying concepts are similar in every library.

Python has [repoze.what](http://what.repoze.org/docs/1.x/).

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) here, for which many open source [libraries](http://oauth.net/code) are available.